# Global filter not working

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have written a function which hides the product visibility if certain needs are meet, it works if I use the following filter.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'tm_remove_product_stock_region', 10,2);
```

The above is ok but when I try to use the following to apply my filter globally when using WP_Query is just won't work.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tm_remove_product_stock_region');
```

I get these two errors "Notice: Undefined variable: product_id", "Warning: Missing argument 2"

I just can't figure out what the issue is.

```
function tm_remove_product_stock_region($query) {    

    $product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable();
    $product_variations = $product_variable->get_available_variations();

    foreach ( $product_variations as $variation ) {

        /** Get users region. */
        $user_region = tm_get_user_region();

        /** Get products regions. */
        $product_region = $variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_regions'];
        if ( $user_region === $product_region && ! $variation['is_in_stock'] ) {

        /** Show product */
        $meta_query = array(
            'key' => '_visibility',
            'value' => 'visible',
            'compare' => '='
         );

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

        }
        else if ( $user_region === $product_region && $variation['is_in_stock'] ) {

         /** Hide product */
        $meta_query = array(
            'key' => '_visibility',
            'value' => 'hidden',
            'compare' => '='
         );

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

        }
    }

   return $query;

}

//Look into apply_filter
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tm_remove_product_stock_region');
```

Comment: $variation['is_in_stock'] is correct check https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_is_in_stock for reference

Comment: 6 days later and I still have not solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really how the pre_get_posts works. The original parameters you've sent to the function are not good.

The only one required is $query.

And the workaround for you will be to run your function in the pre_get_posts function to return an array of post_ID corresponding on the variation you want to include, then in the pre_get_posts function, you will need to `$query->set` arguments, like this (that's just an example, you've got to find the right ones):

```
$query->set('post__in', $include_products);
return $query; // at the end of the function
```

You can read more about the action [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

**UPDATE**
About meta_query argument (also tax_query...) : it always has to be an array of array to enable any relation between different meta_key,
So, your code need to be,

```
$query->set('meta_query', array($meta_query) );
```

Or in a different way embed the array of array directly in `$meta_query`

```
$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key' => '_visibility',
        'value' => 'visible',
        'compare' => '='
     )
);
```

UPDATE 2

You can try to make it easier, using the `WP_Query` `post__in` parameter, but I don't know if it will work as it will depends on the extra woocommerce filter and action to hide product, in that case you might try different priority for the pre_get_posts action :

```
function tm_remove_product_stock_region($query) {

$product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable();
$product_variations = $product_variable->get_available_variations();

// you don't need to run the function in the loop, the user_region is always the same
/** Get users region. */
$user_region = tm_get_user_region();

$post__in = array();

foreach ( $product_variations as $variation ) {

    /** Get products regions. */
    $product_region = $variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_regions'];

    if ( $user_region === $product_region && ! $variation['is_in_stock'] ) {

        $post__in[] = $variation['product_id'];

    }
    else if ( $user_region === $product_region && $variation['is_in_stock'] ) {

        $post__in[] = $variation['product_id'];

    }

}
if(is_array($post__in) && $post__in != null){
    $query->set('post__in', $post__in);
}
return $query;

}

//Look into apply_filter
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tm_remove_product_stock_region');
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I tried this         $meta_query = array(
    'key' => '_visibility',
    'value' => 'visible',
    'compare' => '='
   );

   //$is_visible = false;
   $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query); but still no joy

Comment: Can you update your question and add your new function to it, please.

Comment: I've update my answer ;-) Hope it will work !

Comment: I tried adding the second array to meta_query but the filter is still returning every product, including the ones that are meant to be hidden. Also now it's giving me a notice/warning that says Undefined variable: meta_query.

Comment: You certainly need to extract the $meta query and $query->set from the foreach loop, because you override $meta_query each time the foreach loop. And there is no relation between visible and hidden array. And the undefined is maybe du to the fact that you don't have else clause.

Comment: Would you be able to update your solution with the above comment in mind?

Comment: another solution to test...

Comment: Have a look to another update I've made

Comment: Originally I had $is_visible = false; return $is_visible; for the first if statment and in the second I had $is_visible = true; return $is_visible; which when combined with add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_visible' 'tm_remove_product_stock_region'); worked fined. Is their anyway to pass $is_visible when using pre_get_posts?

Comment: In your first statement you ask for visible and product that are not in stock,  in the second hidden product that are in stock, I just think that that either you made a type or I don't understand exactly which type of product you want to include. The post__in parameter in just an array of the post ID you want to include in the query. For your last question, no it's not possible except if $is_visible is a custom field that you can retrieve and compare with the two different statement and with the same method and meta_query parameter.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, I did try your solution but I'm not sure what wrong. Using custom fields is not an option for me as there are hundreds of products and each has 12 variations. Do you have any other alternative I could try?

Comment: I just think about one thing, there's maybe a typo about is_in_stock, maybe you are trying to get instock (that's the option name of the stock state select dropdown of a variation product). Can you try by changing this in the statements ? is_in_stock -> instock

Comment: Hi Benoti could you tell me the name of the WooCommerce filter and action to hide product?